# angular 2 router is not working on iphone device i have build using cordova

Tags: iphone, angular, cordova

I have createsimple angular2 project make ios build using **cordova** but my default `router` is not loading on **iOS** device it is working fine on browser and android device.Below is the my `app-routing.module.ts` and also i have set the `base href="/"` in `index.html` file

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: do this `base href="." `

Comment: Thanks Parth its work for me

Comment: added as answer, you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
base href="."
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cordova with angular 2+, this is what worked for me:

```
<base href="">
```

So just empty href.

Comment: This answer is too old.